# Can @Component annotated objects be used in an @PreAuthorize method call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I see many examples of passing Strings to custom method calls in the Pre/PostAuthentication annotations. Such as:

```
@Component("authorizationService")
public interface AuthorizationService {
    public boolean hasRoleAccessToActionType(DiceUserDetails userDetails, String action);
}

@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.hasRoleAccessToActionType(principal, 'READ') ")
```

Is it possible to do something like?

```
@Component("authorizationService")
public interface AuthorizationService {
    public static enum ActionType {CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE};
    public boolean hasRoleAccessToActionType(DiceUserDetails userDetails, ActionType actionType);
}

@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.hasRoleAccessToActionType(principal, @authorizationService.ActionType.READ)")
```

Seems like this might not be possible? I would be happy with a set of `static final String`s if the enum is the problem. We are on 3.1 for spring-security and 3.2 for all other spring jars.

Answer (score 0):

The enum is not a problem (Spring coerces String literals to enums if necessary), as long as the method signature is not ambiguous. There is also a 'T' operator in SpEL that you can use to explicitly create enum values or static members of other classes. Docs are [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a convenient way to get `Permission` from its string name, you can use the code below. That way you won't have to duplicate all the permissions Spring ACL gives you already.

```
org.springframework.security.acls.domain.PermissionFactory permissionFactory = new org.springframework.security.acls.domain.DefaultPermissionFactory();
org.springframework.security.acls.model.Permission permission = permissionFactory.buildFromName(name);
```